# openssl: error: 'EC_PRIVATEKEY_it' undeclared here (not in a function)

Tags: openssl, asn.1

I'm using openssl 1.0.2c on Linux and I'm trying to modify a program that is currently using a user-defined ASN1 sequence which includes a `RSAPrivateKey` object.

```
ASN1_NDEF_SEQUENCE(MY_DATA) =
{
    ASN1_SIMPLE(MY_DATA, version, ASN1_INTEGER),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(MY_DATA, key_block_hdr, ASN1_IA5STRING),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(MY_DATA, priv_key, RSAPrivateKey),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(MY_DATA, cert, X509),
    ASN1_OPT(MY_DATA, sign_time, ASN1_UTCTIME)

} ASN1_NDEF_SEQUENCE_END(MY_DATA)

IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(MY_DATA)
```

It's working fine, but I now have to pass an EC key, so I changed the third object to `EC_PRIVATEKEY` (among other changes of course)

```
ASN1_SIMPLE(MY_DATA, priv_key, EC_PRIVATEKEY),
```

This causes the following compile error.

```
error: 'EC_PRIVATEKEY_it' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

I spend a fair amount of time looking at the openssl source (`rsa_asn1.c` / `ec_asn1.c`) and I don't understand why `RSAPrivateKey_it` gets resolved but not `EC_PRIVATEKEY_it`.

I've 'resolved' the compile issue by (blindly) adding the following line

```
`DECLARE_ASN1_ITEM(EC_PRIVATEKEY)`
```

But it's clearly not the right thing to do as I now get a segfault on the `d2i_ECPrivateKey_bio()` call populating the structure.

I'm now wondering if there are limitations with EC keys. 
In others words, am I trying to do something that is not feasible/supported or am I just not doing it the proper way?
The latter is more than probable, so any pointer towards the right direction is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I have made some progress after few days of struggling/learning. It looks like I cannot include a `EC_PRIVATE` object in ASN1 definition. I solved my problem by declaring the private key as  `ASN1_TYPE` / `ASN1_ANY` and building the DER-encoded string with `i2d_PrivateKey()` before calling `i2d_MY_DATA_fp()`. In my particular case,  this has the advantage of handling either RSA or EC private keys. I used `PKCS8_pkey_set0()` as reference.